# How to place ACF get_field inside an array post__in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the code below but it’s just posting one post or showing 1 post but if i add the post id inside the array it working, but if i add the `$tguides_value` its just showing one item

```
<?php
  $tguides_value = get_field('recommended_tguides');

         $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'travelguides',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__in' => array($tguides_value),
```

**Question:** How would I place the ACF `get_field` inside the array `post__in` in Wordpress

Comment: what values does your acf field return?

Comment: Have you tried using get_field_object($selector) then in 'post__in' use $tguides_value['id']

Comment: @DanielVickers If i echo the acf field, it return the number,  i tried using the get field object but its just outputting the latest post

Comment: No wonder it’s only showing one post then if the number being output is just 1 you can’t expect it to show all post ids with the value?

Comment: @DanielVickers, I have a custom field where in i added 3 post id manually but right now its just showing one

Comment: Ahh right so the issue it seems is that you’re getting the field which I assume you comma separate however that doesn’t turn it into an array you need to get the field and then explode it at comma and turn it into an array and then pass that in the query google turn comma separated text into array php

Answer (score 0):

Try using as follows,

```
$tguides_value = get_field('recommended_tguides', $postID);

         $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'travelguides',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__in' => array($tguides_value),
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but, still the same. Showing 1 post

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to output 3 post, using the custom field that im using, Example i added 3 post id in the custom field but its just showing 1 post even i added 3 post id

Comment: I tried double checking it,

If i use this            'post__in' => array(100,101,103), = Its working
but if i use this one its not working             'post__in' => array($tguides_value), (its only showing 1 post

Comment: when you use 100,101 and 103, its three values whilst when you use $tguides_value it's just one value. try using a loop to store all three values into array

Comment: Another thing, if you need to store three different numbers, using single ACF field would be a bad idea. use repeater field or use three different text fields

Comment: It’s because he has a text field and he is trying to use it as an array without exploding to make an array from the text field

Comment: @DanielVickers yes, that what I tried to say above, you just said it better I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your text field return of a string into an array by exploding at the comma, you can't just pass your text string into it as an array.

```
<?php
  $tguides_value = get_field('recommended_tguides');
  $tguides_array = explode (",", $tguides_value);

         $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'travelguides',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__in' => $tguides_array,
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out thanks to your help Daniel Vickers, but it should be `implode` instead of `explode`.

Here is what I ended up doing for myself in my particular use and it worked:

```
    <?php
    $values = get_field('homepage_magic_test');
    $valuett = implode(",",$values);
    ?>
    <?php get_jig(array(
        'img_alt_field' => 'alternate',
        'title_field' => 'title',
        'recent_posts' => 'yes',
        'recents_title_override' => 'custom_title',
        'recents_post_type' => 'page',
        'post_ids' => $valuett
    ));
        ?>
```

So I assume the following would work for the code above.

```
$tguides_value = get_field('recommended_tguides');
$tguides_imp = implode(",",$tguides_value);

         $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'travelguides',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__in' => $tguides_imp,
```